# BindableProperty does not update when part of bindable object updates

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use BindableProperty from a Binding in the parent.

Header.xaml.cs:

```
        public static readonly BindableProperty UserProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
             nameof(User),
             typeof(User),
             typeof(Header),
             null,
             defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
             propertyChanged: UpdateUser
        );

        private static void UpdateUser(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = bindable as Header;
            control.OnLoggedInLoggedOut((User) newValue);
        }
```

The User comes from ChallengeViewModel.cs:

```
        private User user;
        public User User
        {
            get
            {
                return user;
            }
            set
            {
                user = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnLoginLogout();
            }
        }
```

If I am updating the entire User object with a new one, e.g. User = new User(); it works.
But if I am only updating part of the object, e.g. User.Name, it will be updated in this part:
`user = value;` but not in the BindableProperty.

Is there a way I can fix that or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: does `User` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes, in `OnPropertyChanged()`. It also updates correctly if I update the entire model. But not if only partially update.

Comment: no, does `User` actually **implement** `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  **implement** has a specific meaning in C#.  Just having a `PropertyChanged` method is not sufficient

Comment: Yes. `public class ChallengePageViewModel : BaseViewModel` and `public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: This is now the **third time** I've asked - does **User** implement INPC?  You are asking about properties of the `User` object, so that class needs to implement INPC

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. But you were right. I though it was implemented, but it had the method in the class but not the implementation. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `User`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.name)
            {
                this.name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```